# Make Zxying output to form?

Tags: javascript, html

Using ZXying is there a way to make it output to a form? I tried to add id 'dbr' however it does not populate.

```html
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="AddItemDescription">Item Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Whatever" name="Item_Description"
                  placeholder="QR">
            </div>
```

```html
  <div>Barcode result: <span id="dbr" name='2Item'></span></div>
  <div class="select">
    <label for="videoSource">Video source: </label><select id="videoSource"></select>
  </div>
  <button id="go">Read Barcode</button>
  <div>
    <video muted autoplay id="video" playsinline="true"></video>
    <canvas id="pcCanvas" width="640" height="480" style="display: none; float: bottom;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="mobileCanvas" width="240" height="320" style="display: none; float: bottom;"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean zxing barcode scanner?

Comment: Yea sorry I didnt make that clear from the onset.